# JsPDF addImage jpeg background is black

Tags: javascript, canvas, png, jpeg, jspdf

I use JsPDF library and I have a problem, when I use addImage format 'JPEG' my background is black. Why this format? Because when I use format "PNG" - size file PDF after saving 12 charts = 100 MB ++ . I see all question and does not find the exact answer to it.
My functions looks like that:

```
<canvas id = 'myCanvas'></canvas>

var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a2');
var canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
doc.addImage(canvasImg,'JPEG', 70,700,1000,300 ); //left, from above, width, height
doc.addHTML($(id_page),function(){
  doc.save('test.pdf');
});
```

This is default template, but i tried add more style including "setFillColor" - uselessly! Tried add white canvas with "destination-over", nice idea but... realization, today 2018 year, may be who find working solution, I really hope at least for some working information. Many thanks.

Comment: I use Chart.js may be will help

Comment: Use PNG instead. JPEG is not transparent but PNG is

Comment: @UllasHunka see above)) " I use addImage format 'JPEG' my background is black. Why this format? Because when I use format "PNG" - size file PDF after saving 12 charts = 100 MB ++"

Comment: That's the truth. JPEGs are for photographs and realistic images. PNGs are for line art, text-heavy images, and images with few colors. But you can't seem getaway if you want good quality.

Comment: @UllasHunka quality it's not problem, user's have very weak computers, and save file 100mb+ bad idea((

Answer (score 5):

PNGs support alpha channels (transparency) while JPEGs do not.

A workaround would be to fill the canvas with any background color you prefer before exporting.

After the canvas is created and *before* you call Chart.js to draw the charts, create a context and fill the entire canvas with whatever colors you prefer.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Look at the question, he has "Tried add white canvas" but he wants another workaround.

Comment: @UllasHunka "may be who find working solution, I really hope at least for some working information." I'm guessing it didn't quite work out.....

Comment: @Umang Raghuvanshi wow, this work, but I get canvas full shaded color)) and WEB canvas fill's background

Comment: @UmangRaghuvanshi may be try out globalCompositeOperation, but I use it, dont work for me((